# Fresh install of JDBC for Oracle - does not execute

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This is my first attempt to connect to an Oracle DB (10g) using JDBC. I have JDK 6 installed on my machine and trying to connect to an Oracle DB on a server. I have downloaded **ojdbc6.jar** and copied it to **C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib**.

I have also set the following CLASS PATH:

```
.;
C:\;
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jlib\orai18n.jar;
C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip
```

The following code gets compiled, however when I try to run the class file, it throws an error

```
C:\>java JDBCVersion
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at JDBCVersion.main(JDBCVersion.java:10)
```

I save my .java files in C:\ to compile and run from this directory.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

class JDBCVersion
{

  public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException{
  try{
  Connection con=null;
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      con=DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOSTNAME:1521:MYORADB",
        "SCOTT",
        "TIGER");
      Statement s=con.createStatement();
      s.execute("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE");
      s.close();
      con.close();
   } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }
 }
```

@dardo...I added the .jar file directly in the CLASSPATH and it compiled but when I run the class file I get the following error message

```
C:\>java JDBCVersion
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.convert
er.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/CharacterConverter;
        at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.make(CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.java:43)
        at oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.getInstance(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:97)
        at oracle.sql.CharacterSetFactoryThin.make(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:129)
        at oracle.sql.CharacterSet.make(CharacterSet.java:514)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.init(DBConversion.java:169)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.<init>(DBConversion.java:120)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1135)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at JDBCVersion.main(JDBCVersion.java:15)
```

Comment: that should work, check to make sure your classpath is as you expect, most likely you will find a typo of some sort.

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens when you run `java -jar -classpath .;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar; jarName.jar`

Comment: @dardo....this comment box is too small for the error output. So I added my response in my original question.

Comment: Did you add both jars (`ojdbc6.jar` and `orai18n`) to the classpath?

Comment: @madth3....just now I added **orail8n** to the CLASSPATH. Then I recompiled it and when I ran the class file, I get the same error message as posted above.

Comment: Do I have to assign/grant any permissions at the Oracle DB itself?

Comment: I purposely just added the one to see if the exception would change.  The entire classpath should be something like:  `java -jar -classpath .;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jlib\orai18n.jar;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip; jarName.jar`

Comment: @dardp...ok instead of running this at the command prompt, I replaced the CLASS PATH variables with your classpath. It works (wohoooo) and "s.execute(sql statement)" returns True and which means it is connecting to the database. Thank you so much...you are my new best friend!!!

Comment: @ dardo...please post your answer as a seperate answer instead of a comment so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing with the following command should get it to run.

```
java -jar -classpath .;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0‌​\client_1\jlib\orai18n.jar;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip; jarName.jar
```

But, you might want to look into packaging these jars with your executable rather than setting the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that something is wrong with your classpath.

Try adding the jar with driver to your project directly and see, whether it works. Then I would check for typos in your CP.