# java.lang.NoSchMethodError: oracle.i118n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstancec(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/ChatacterConverter;

Tags: java, jdbc, nosuchmethoderror

Ok this problem has stumped me completly, and I sure hope someone has an answer before I give up on this project completly.

Basicly I am trying to connect from a website pointing to a java servlet(2.5) and from there I want to use JDBC to connect to the DB.

The user and password are the DB credentials.

Now when I use the same dbconn file with a java class (printing success to the console) everything works like a charm, but if I try doing the same thing with the servlet it produces the error which can be seen below.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /ClassChat/LogonSRV. Reason:
  Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.NoSchMethodError: oracle.i118n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstancec(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/ChatacterConverter;
      at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.make(CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.java:43)
      at oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.getInstance(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:95)
      at oracle.sql.CharacterSetFactoryThin.make(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:95)
  at oracle.sql.CharacterSet.make(CharacterSet.java:450)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.init(DBConversion.java:151)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.<init>(DBConversion.java:112)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConection.connect(T4CConection.java:1075)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConection.logon(T4CConection.java:301)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(T4CConection.java:221)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConection.<init>(DBConversion.java:151)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
  at bl.dbConn.getConnection(dbConn.java:32)
  at bl.Conny.Conns(Conny.java:30)
  at bl.LogonSRV.service(LogonSRV.java:26)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
  ....
  ....
```

> a link to the full error list : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9DrL.jpg

I have attached the correct Jars for JDBC & Servlets, and tried every trick in the book including calling a regular java class which in turn calls the connection.

To make it easier to find the error, here is some of the code I am using:

**[Line 26 in bl.LogonSRV]** (the line producing the error).

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // Get the data from the jsp.
  String strUser = request.getParameter("username");
  String strPass = request.getParameter("password");

  // In case this is the first time the page is loading.
  if (strUser == null) {
    // Redirect to login page.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
  } else {
    // Connect to the DB (the line producing the error).
    String Error = Conny.Conns(strUser, strPass);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Success.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

**[Line 30 in bl.Conny]** (the line producing the error).

```
public static String Conns(String User, String Pass) {

  Connection conni = null;
  String Error = null;

  try {
    conni = dbConn.getInstance().getConnection(User, Pass);
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Error = "Error in connection"; 
  }

   return (Error)
}
```

**[Line 32 in bl.dbConn]** (the line producing the error).

```
// Connect to the DB.
public Connection getConnection(String Username, String Password) throws SQLException {

  return (DriverManager.getConnection(SERVER_ADDRESS, Username, Password));

}
```

P.S. I know the connection needs to be closed, and that sending password is not safe, but first I want to see that it works, and how to fix this error.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943379/fresh-install-of-jdbc-for-oracle-does-not-execute

Comment: put your stack trace in the question instead of linking off to an image file

Comment: I wish i could add the picture but because i am a new user i cant yet.

Comment: add the stack trace as text, not a picture

Comment: @aguibert I added most of it as text, but to see the full error you will have to click the link

Comment: @Sneh I don't see any relevant answers there.

Comment: Please recheck your jars - especially those provided by the servlet container (tomcat/lib) mismatched driver versions would be one possible reason.

Comment: @RabbiShuki I think this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror
Also try running your code from command line by calling the Conny.Conns(strUser, strPass) from a java main method. In process you will find out exactly what dependencies are required.

Comment: restart your application server

Comment: Why aren't you testing the `Error` string returned? Why are you *returning* an error string, instead of letting the exception be caught byt the caller? Some poor practice here.

Comment: @Agbalaya did that same result.

Comment: @EJP i tried the regular way, and after hours of trying to pinpoint the error this is where i am stuck.

Comment: You've just duplicate different versioned Oracle JDBC driver JAR files in runtime classpath conflicting each other.

Comment: @BalusC so how can i find where and fix it?

Comment: There are two typos just in the first line of your stacktrace (getInstancec() ... ChaTacterConverter). Why?

Comment: @Gergely Basco since i cant post a picture, i basicly retyped the error message. No internet on the computer that i am coding on.

Comment: Once more: search all files ojdbc* in your application and container libraries - most likely you have two different versions of them running around conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the help, the problem ended up being that i had a previous .jar file on the project which was deleted but i didnt go through the deployment process again after deleting it.

I gues there are somethings you can only learn the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

It may also occur when one has incompatible ojdbc driver and JDK along with orai18n.jar.
Using compatible ojdbc solved the problem for me.

Check the Oracle [compatibility matrices](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_01) for the appropriate ojdbc version.

Comment: This Question is 3 years old! I would guess that I don't need the answer anymore. but maybe it will help someone else. thanks.

Comment: @RabbiShukiGur That was my original thought...adding another scenario for someone facing the same problem, since It took me a while to figure out. I guess it could also be added as a comment :).